# NativeScript nativescript-drop-down doesn't read list items correctly

Tags: nativescript

NativeScript newbie here. Trying to add a dropdown / combobox style widget. Looks like [nativescript-drop-down](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-drop-down) should be close. The [Demo](https://github.com/peterstaev/nativescript-drop-down) runs fine but the plugin has two problems in our app. First, the selection items show in the picker as [object Object],[object Object], ... instead of: Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, ...

Second, the contents of the scroll wheel shows just one character per "row", so above [object Object] actually shows on spinner as:

```
[
o
j
e
c
t

O
b
j
e
c
t
]
,
[
o
...
```

Related, if we store just strings instead of ValueItems into the ValueList, we get similar results, just one character (instead of one item) on each spinner "row."

Key code snippets:

From page layout:

```
<DropDown row="0" col="2" class="time-button-selected" hint="Time?" items="{{ hourItems }}"></DropDown>
```

From component typescript:

```
    <deletia...>
```

@Component({
    selector: "Order",
    templateUrl: "./order.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./order.component.scss']
})

export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {

```
    <deletia...>

hourItems = new ValueList<string>();

constructor(private platformHelper: PlatformHelperService,
            private appStateService: AppStateService) {

    <deletia...>

    for (let loop = 0; loop < 20; loop++) { 
        let vi:ValueItem<string> = { value: `I${loop}`, display: `Item ${loop}`};
        this.hourItems.push(vi);
    }

}

    <deletia...>
```

}

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried setting `[items]="hourItems"` in your template, instead of `{{ hourItems}}`?

Comment: Hey @Bass - That was it!! Holy crap - we spent hours and hours on this, and all we needed was [items]="hourItems" instead of {{ hourItems }}. One of those "easy once you know" issues, I guess. Thanks!!!